# Infinite amount of Collection VBA

Tags: vba, collections

Here is the screen of my problem which is infinite amount of collections.
I want the collection be added to object property just once. Not like this:

http://postimg.org/image/o6da95j0f/
(screen showing the problem with "watch" of collection in VBA

```
    Public Sub testCollections()

Dim index As Long
index = 1
    Dim OJsonElement As JsonElement
    Dim newColl As New Collection
    Dim str As String
    Call addColl(OJsonElement, newColl)


    For Each OJsonElement In newColl
    Debug.Print "THE NAME IS:" & OJsonElement.name
    Next OJsonElement

End Sub


Function addColl(obj1 As JsonElement, nextCollection As Collection)
Dim i As Long
Set nextCollection = New Collection
Set obj1 = New JsonElement
Set obj1.valueCollection = nextCollection
obj1.name = "CityName"
obj1.value = "type"
nextCollection.Add obj1


'obj1.ValueType = nextCollection


'nextCollection.Add nextCollection



End Function

Class:
Public name As String
Public nameCollection As Collection
Public value As Variant
Public ValueType As String
Public valueCollection As Collection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand well your code, but I will limit to explain you why it happens what you see in your watcher. The line:

```
Set obj1.valueCollection = nextCollection
```

is adding the new collection into the `obj1` property `valueCollection`. Then, two lines after, you say:

```
nextCollection.Add obj1
```

which means you're adding the `obj1` into its own property, so creating an infinite nesting. I'd like to help you but for that I'd need to understand what you want to reach with your code. But sticking to your request *I want the collection be added to object property just once*, I would just suggest you to remove the line `nextCollection.Add obj1`, which (at least from the perspective of who doesn't know the project purpose) does not seem to do anything useful but an infinite nesting.